# Декодировать строку Python

Tags: python

Моя программа выдает мне закодированный текст. Как в питоне я могу такое расшифровать?

=?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsDE=?=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это mime headers (RFC 2047). Используется в email. В питоне есть модуль для [работы с этим](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header).

```
from email.header import decode_header
bstr, encoding = decode_header('=?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsDE=?=')[0]
decoded = bstr.decode(encoding)
print(decoded)
```

Результат

```
Проверка1
```